# Fullcalendar window.print();

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i am using this scheduler

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-resource-render-hook-demo
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001

with this setup
but I have problems.

- 1st problem in printing I do not print the calendar grid
- 2nd problem setup on A3 horizontal sheet with 0.5mm margins
- 3rd problem once the print is launched the calendar stops working, you can do the test by clicking on the cell.

Please help me.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    customButtons: {
          printBtn: {
            text: 'Stampa',
            click: function() { 
                var printContents = document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML;
                var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;                
                document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
                var css = '@page { size: A3 landscape; }',
                head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.media = 'print';
                if (style.styleSheet){
                  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                } else {
                  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                }
                head.appendChild(style);
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
              }              
            }          
        },
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next printBtn',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    firstDay:1,
    locale:'it',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    slotLabelInterval: { days: 1 },  
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',

    resourceLabelDidMount: function(info) {
      var questionMark = document.createElement('strong');
      questionMark.innerText = ' (?) ';

      info.el.querySelector('.fc-datagrid-cell-main')
        .appendChild(questionMark);

      var tooltip = new Tooltip(questionMark, {
        title: info.resource.title + '!!!',
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    },
    selectable: true,      
    editable: true,
    select: function (event,date) {
       alert("Click select");
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: 1st probleem: This seems to be more like a statement than a question.

Comment: 2nd problem: Yeas what is with this horizontal sheet with 0.5 mm margins?

Comment: 3rd problem: When you printed something (on paper) it stop working too, so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Please only ask 1 question at a time, and not 3... (or they should be better explained, and related)